# Json to Table format using shell script

Tags: shell-script, json

sfdx diff | tee result.json ;

Here i am getting result/response in json which i am adding to  result.json file.
Below is the json i am getting

```json
{
  "status": 3,
  "result": {
    "source": {
      "type": "folder",
      "origin": "/source"
    },
    "target": {
      "type": "folder",
      "origin": "/target"
    },
    "difs": [
      {
        "type": "In Progress",
        "entity": "Phone",
        "result": "added"
      },
      {
        "type": "Completed",
        "entity": "SMS",
        "result": "added"
      },
      {
        "type": "Scheduled",
        "entity": "Web",
        "result": "added"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I need to show it in table format ..like
[image]

Is there any way we can do it.Please help as i am very new to shell script

Comment: Your JSON seems broken (it looks like an array, but there are no `[` or `]`, and there's a trailing comma at the end, and there is other data at the start (`source`, `origin`, `type` and `status` but no `Status`)). You expected output is an _image_?

Comment: no .If you read my comment ,i am expecting output in a table format .Ignore the mistakes in Json as i have provided sample JSON.

Comment: I mentioned my requirement is to show json data in table format and format  needs to be like attached image..

Comment: The image looks like it's from a spreadsheet program. Do you want the output to be in Excel format, or in a format that Excel (or OpenOffice) can read?  Would CSV be ok, for example? Or do you want an actual image?

Comment: I can't _ignore_ the errors in the JSON, sorry. Consider updating your question with a correctly formatted JSON file that is representative of the JSON document that you have. Without this, we have to _guess_ what your actual data looks like and any answer may be nonfunctional for you.

Comment: @Kusalananda -   I have updated the json ... and the result i want is to say html data in PDF file.......

Comment: like here  after running this command  ==>  sfdx diff | tee result.json    I am getting output.json file and i need to show in html format and save it in pdf file ... so that users/customer can read it better way.. jSON is not that much good to read. I hope you understand the requirement and looking for  inputs  to implement this. Thanks in advance

Comment: The `json`  is still invalid, and you could improve readability by proper indenting ... However, you sould show what you've tried and where you're stuck! This site should not be seen as a code-writing service, however we are glad to help with **your** code.

Comment: Have you tried to find out if the 'sfdx' command is capable already of outputting HTML results?

Answer (score 5):

Given the JSON document that is currently in the question, the following `jq` command would transform it into a CSV form that corresponds to the table format that you show, including the table header:

```bsh
jq -r '["Status","Value","Result"],
    (.result.difs[] | [.type,.entity,.result]) | @csv' file.json
```

This first creates an array of the values for each row that we need to convert into CSV, and then uses the built-in `@csv` operator to create properly quoted CSV data.

The output, given the example JSON document, would be

```
"Status","Value","Result"
"In Progress","Phone","added"
"Completed","SMS","added"
"Scheduled","Web","added"
```

This could later be imported into whatever spreadsheet program you want to use to create your table.

Post-processing this with `cvslook` from the `csvkit` toolkit of command line CSV parsing tools, you can get a markdown variant of the table:

```bsh
jq -r '["Status","Value","Result"],
    (.result.difs[] | [.type,.entity,.result]) | @csv' file.json |
csvlook
```

This would output

```
| Status      | Value | Result |
| ----------- | ----- | ------ |
| In Progress | Phone | added  |
| Completed   | SMS   | added  |
| Scheduled   | Web   | added  |
```

which, when rendered as markdown would look like

| Status | Value | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| In Progress | Phone | added |
| Completed | SMS | added |
| Scheduled | Web | added |